# Results of MDX query against missing partition - Tabular 2012

Tags: mdx, tabular

UPDATE: the resolution was to do a process full at the database level instead of at the partition level.

I am trying to understand the behavior I am observing with a query a Tabular model.  I partition by quarter, so when I built a new "current quarter" partition at the start of this quarter, the partition that used to contain 2016-Q4 was overwritten with 2017-Q1.  Then when I ran my MDX query against the Tabular model filtering on the date dimension for 2016-Q4, instead of returning nothing like I would have expected, it returned data from the oldest partition 2014-Q1.  It is like instead of returning no data, it decides to return the "first record" for that dimension (in this case all dates where 07/01/2014). Every other dimension I was filtering on still performed as expected.

Does anybody have any ideas as to why it behaves this way?  FYI, I have tried restructuring my MDX statement a couple different ways:

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Measure1]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([Dimension].[Dimension1])} DIMENSION PROPERTIES member_caption, member_unique_name ON ROWS 
FROM [Model] WHERE ([Dimension].[Dimension2].&[Value], [DateDimension].[DateDimension].&[Value1] : [DateDimension].[DateDimension].&[Value2])
```

AND

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Measure1]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ( except([Dimension].[Dimension1].members,[Dimension].[Dimension1].[all]))} DIMENSION PROPERTIES member_caption, member_unique_name ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( [Dimension].[Dimension1].&[Value] ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( [Dimension].[Dimension2].&[Value] ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( [DateDimension].[DateDimension].&[Value1] : [DateDimension].[DateDimension].&[Value2] ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Model])))
```

Edit: added example of actual MDX

```
SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[ConvertedNetRevenue], 
[Measures].[LoadConvertedNetRevenue], 
[Measures].[OrderConvertedNetRevenue], 
[Measures].[TotalOrderBrokerageCount], 
[Measures].[TotalLoadBrokerageCount]   
} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { 
( 
except([BrokerageQuery].[KeyBranch].members,[BrokerageQuery].[KeyBranch].[all]),
except([BrokerageQuery].[LoadNumber].members,[BrokerageQuery].[LoadNumber].[all]),
except([BrokerageQuery].[CustomerOrderNumber].members,[BrokerageQuery].[CustomerOrderNumber].[all]),
except([BrokerageQuery].[BranchName].members,[BrokerageQuery].[BranchName].[all]),
except([BrokerageQuery].[BranchCode].members,[BrokerageQuery].[BranchCode].[all]),
except([BrokerageQuery].[BranchRoleDescription].members,[BrokerageQuery].[BranchRoleDescription].[all]),
except([BrokerageQuery].[ModeDescription].members,[BrokerageQuery].[ModeDescription].[all]),
except([BrokerageQuery].[ServiceTypeDescription].members,[BrokerageQuery].[ServiceTypeDescription].[all]),
except([BrokerageQuery].[SystemDisplayName].members,[BrokerageQuery].[SystemDisplayName].[all]),
except([BrokerageQuery].[IsPartialFinLock].members,[BrokerageQuery].[IsPartialFinLock].[all]),
except([BrokerageQuery].[KeyDate_Financial].members,[BrokerageQuery].[KeyDate_Financial].[all])
) 
} DIMENSION PROPERTIES member_caption, member_unique_name ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT 
( 
{ 
[dimCurrency].[CurrencyCode].&[USD] 
} 
) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT 
( 
{ 
{ 
[BrokerageQuery].[KeyBranch].[10279]
} 
} 
) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT 
( 
[BrokerageQuery].[KeyDate_Financial].&[20161106] : 
[BrokerageQuery].[KeyDate_Financial].&[20161106] 
) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Brokerage])))
```

Comment: Can you include your actual MDX query verbatim? I'm assuming what you have isn't real since it says Value1?

Comment: Sure, updated with actual MDX. I do suspect that this isn't necessarily an issue with the MDX, but rather how Tabular handles "missing" data, does that make sense?

Comment: If you just run the following part of the query what does it return? I'm checking that date exists. SELECT  (  [BrokerageQuery].[KeyDate_Financial].&[20161106] :  [BrokerageQuery].[KeyDate_Financial].&[20161106]  ) ON COLUMNS  FROM [Brokerage]

Comment: Did you create a new 2017-Q1 partition? Or did you change just the SQL query for the 2016-Q4 partition to retrieve 2017-Q1 data? Did you process the table or partition or model? Did you change this in SSMS or SSDT?

Comment: Running the query returns results for 20140701.  For the partitions, I changed the SQL query to retrieve data for 2017-Q1.  A new partition is not added.  I processed the individual partition, not the table or model.  The change to the SQL query (which is a stored procedure) is done via parameters hardcoded in the partition manager of the model itself that represent the number of quarters offset from today's date.  So partition 1 will always be current quarter. Partition 2 will always be current quarter minus 1, and so on.

Comment: Do the 20140701 rows have KeyDate_Financial=20161106? Why did 2014 data get returned when you asked for 2016?

Comment: I have an idea as to the root cause of this issue! Since we have a rolling partitioning strategy, the dictionary that Tabular uses to 'find' data becomes out-of-date. When we effectively drop a partition, the dictionary still retains that data, and if we filter on a value that is in the dictionary but NOT actually in the partition, we get these kind of results. The solution I am exploring is using a Process Defrag in our process, likely immediately after rebuilding the partitions for a new quarter. This will clean up the dictionary. Thanks for the help, GregGalloway :)

Comment: process defrag shouldn't ever change results just optimize memory usage and performance. How long does ProcessFull on the whole database take? That would certainly be safest if you have time.

Comment: When we rebuild each partition at the start of a new quarter, we do a process full on each partition. We also do a process full on each dimension table.  I could test to see if doing a process full at the database-level would produce different results, but I am convinced that the process defrag fixed this issue.  A process full (table/partition level) takes just over 3 hours for everything.

Comment: Doing a process full at the database level achieves the same result as running the process defrag (then process recalc) after doing a process full at the partition level.  So we are going to change how we process at the start of each quarter and do a database-level process full at that time. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of processing our partitions individually (at the beginning of each quarter when re-partitioning occurs), we need to do a database-level process full.